# Find the following limit.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

**Question.** Find the limit of the following $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int^{\infty}_0n\ln\Big(1+\frac{e^{-x}}{n}\Big).$$

---

Now here's my attempt

Define $$f_n(x)=n\ln\Big(1+\frac{e^{-x}}{n}\Big)=\ln\Big(1+\frac{e^{-x}}{n}\Big)^n\Rightarrow e^{f_n(x)}=\Big(1+\frac{e^{-x}}{n}\Big)^n.$$ But now I'm finding it hard to find a function that dominates $f_n(x)$ because I feel that using Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem is the way to go here.

---

Also as an aside, do any of you know any resources that has similar questions like this as I feel as though I need more practice on these sorts of problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: $\left(1+\frac an\right)^n$ converges monotonically to $e^a$.

Comment: Ah okay, so we can use the monotone convergence theorem to get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int^{\infty}_0f_n(x)=\int^{\infty}_0e^{-x}$$ by following your hint?

Comment: Indeed${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! As for the second part of my question, do you know of any resources that has these types of questions?

Comment: No, not really, unless browsing this site counts.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int _{0}^{\infty} n \ln \left( 1+\frac{e^{-z}}{n}\right) dx
=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} n \left(\frac{e^{-x}}{n}-\frac{e^{-2x}}{n^2}+...\right) dx =\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} dx=1.$$